# Smartclt doesn't show Power_on_hours

Tags: ssd, smartctl

I have bought used ssd msata disk to check whether it will work with my notebook. I have also tested smartclt values to get info about worked hours. There is no `Power_on_hours` entry. I have tried `--attributes`, `--all`, `-a`, and `-x` flags. But no similar values.

Smartctl output:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3349
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   088   088   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       135
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       4356
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       30329673756
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       34142273703
```

What is more interesting LBA are very high, e.g. my disk has 6 years, I have been using it normally and it has 5 times less LBA. Is it possible to delete `Power_on_hours` entry? Or should I read it in other way?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to delete Power_on_hours entry?

I guess you meant something different, please edit your question. S.M.A.R.T. values cannot be deleted or hidden. SMART was designed to be tamper-proof, so you're only allowed to query SMART values and execute tests. That's it.

> Or should I read it in other way?

smartctl shows all the attributes even if it doesn't properly understand/know them. Looks like your device lacks this metric.

> What is more interesting LBA are very high, e.g. my disk has 6 years, I have been using it normally and it has 5 times less LBA.

People have very different usage patterns, so it makes no sense to compare your write/read values with someone else's.

Comment: `SMART was designed to be tamper-proof`   while I do not disagree, old nvidia gpu chip firmware has been reburnt so it shows up as a later model chip, i.e. counterfeit, and has been sold on ebay, amazon, etc.  There are articles about it, since maybe 2010.  I would bet $1 this can be done with a firmware flash on sata disks, the opportunity is just too juicy to resell used SSD's **in my opinion**.  And my experience is SMARTCTL does not always work flawlessly with every disk, some make & models show more smartctl parameters than others.

Comment: if an SSD is sold and marked as "used" then that is fine.  But any *new* disk purchased especially from amazon or ebay it would be prudent for anyone to know how to *smartctl* it; if you do see an unacceptable power-on-hours value or something similar indicating usage then know you didn't purchase a new disk.

Comment: @ron The ability to flash a GPU ROM is very different from being able to meddle with HDD/SSD ROM. The GPU does not contain any form of persistent memory. While modern SSD's allow to update firmware they still keep SMART parameters intact, i.e. you're only allowed to rewrite the portion of ROM which is a program. You cannot touch the data. I've never in my life seen a successful attempt of erasing SMART parameters, though I'm sure OEMs can do that themselves - after all they control everything.